# Is it possible to use Amazon AWS iOS framework for macOS?

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, cocoa

In the [AWS Developers Tools](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/), there is not macOS SDK, I wonder if is it possible to use the provided iOS SDK to create macOS apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you would normally use one of the other supported languages like [Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/), [Python](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/) and so on.  A "native" library for Mac OS/X could be the [C++](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/) library.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's a popular [open request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/498), since at least [2010](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=56315).

The aws/aws-sdk-ios project on GitHub has 400 forks (!), and several are partial Mac ports, but there's nothing complete or official yet.